# Can the cut command accept newline as a delimiter?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file, foo.txt, with 2 lines:

```
foo bar
hello world
```

I am trying to output the second line using:

```
cut -d$'\n' -f2 foo.txt
```

But it is printing both lines instead.

Is cut able to accept a newline as a delimiter?

Comment: "EDIT: To clarify [...] where I can capture "foo bar" as one variable and "hello world lorem ipsum" as another variable." And then what do you do with the variables? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: I think it would better to ask another question and then link it here, as IMO my post answers the original question appropriately and the new information from the edit changes the question completely IMO.

Comment: @dan "GNU and Busybox cut both accept new line as the delimiter. I have used this many times to print multiple line ranges etc. I tested your example and it printed the second line. Which OS? Can you try `-d "$(printf '\n')"`" Care to give an example? I tried `printf 'foo bar1\nfoo bar2\n' | cut -f 2 -d "$(printf '\n')"` before posting my answer and it printed the input as is (using bash/GNU coreutils).

Comment: @kelvin I should not have suggested command sub printf, that was dumb. Trailing new lines are stripped. `$'\n'` is valid bash. You can also use `nl=$(printf '\n:'); nl=${nl%:}`. My example will be stripped of new lines also because it's a comment: `$ cat foo.txt;
foo bar
hello world
$ cut -d$'\n' -f2 foo.txt;
hello world` you'll have to take my word the new lines are where you would expect if cut worked this way.

Comment: GNU and Busybox cut both accept new line as the delimiter. I have used this many times to print multiple line ranges etc. I tested your example and it printed the second line. Which OS? Can you try `nl=$(printf '\n:'); nl=${nl%:}; cut -d "$nl" -f 2'`, and also confirm your shell is bash, with echo "$0"? I checked POSIX (2018) and the cut specification isn't 100% clear IMO. It uses the term "fields". The closest to touching on this that I could find: "Lines with no field delimiters shall be passed through intact, unless -s is specified.".

Comment: @dan "GNU and Busybox cut both accept new line as the delimiter. I have used this many times to print multiple line ranges etc. I tested your example and it printed the second line. Which OS? Can you try nl=$(printf '\n:'); nl=${nl%:}; cut -d "$nl" -f 2'" Very interesting; it worked with `nl=$(printf '\n:'); nl=${nl%:}; printf 'foo bar1\nfoo bar2\n' | cut -d "$nl" -f 2`. I thought it wasn't possible to store a newline in a variable in a POSIX shell and I wonder how portable that trick  is. Either way, I think that you should post that as an answer.

Comment: While [edit]s to the question to provide clarification and/or additional information are encouraged, edits which change the question sufficiently to invalidate an already posted answer are not permitted, even if you didn't actually ask the question you intended. In fact, the consensus is that any user with [edit privileges](/help/privileges/edit) should revert such edits. I have done so here. Please note that this doesn't prevent you from completely changing a question prior to any answers being posted. If you desire, you're welcome to post a [new question](/questions/ask) on your new issue.

Answer (score 4):

#### Background

`cut` operates on all lines of the input, so I don't think that a newline can
work as a delimiter.

From [`cut(1p)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) of POSIX.1-2017:

> ```
> NAME
>
>     cut - cut out selected fields of each line of a file
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
>     cut -b list [-n] [file...]
>
>     cut -c list [file...]
>
>     cut -f list [-d delim] [-s] [file...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
>     The cut utility shall cut out bytes (-b option), characters (-c option), or
>     character-delimited fields ( -f option) from each line in one or more
>     files, concatenate them, and write them to standard output.
> ```

Example:

```
$ printf 'foo bar1\nfoo bar2\n'
foo bar1
foo bar2
$ printf 'foo bar1\nfoo bar2\n' | cut -f 2 -d ' '
bar1
bar2
```

#### Solution

To print only the second line of input, `sed` can be used:

```
$ printf 'foo bar1\nfoo bar2\n'
foo bar1
foo bar2
$ printf 'foo bar1\nfoo bar2\n' | sed '2p;d'
foo bar2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want, but this is splitting on empty lines and collapsing the others using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=""} {gsub("\n",""); print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

this might not be a very elegant solution, but i often just use `head` and `tail`, since they typically outperform `sed` or `awk` in speed

```sh
#!/bin/sh

input='test0\ntest1\ntest2\ntest3\ntest4\ntest5'


echo -e "$input" | head --lines 3
# test0
# test1
# test2

echo -e "$input" | tail --lines 3
# test3
# test4
# test5

get_index() {
    echo -e "$1" |
        head --lines "$(( $2 + 1 ))" |
        tail --lines "1"
}

get_index "$input" "0"
# test0

get_index "$input" "4"
# test4
```